# Java EE with JPA, strange database generated

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish-3, netbeans-8

I'm trying to understand how JPA is working by making some POC on my own.

I've created some entities, who are something like that :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="SKILLS_EMPLOYEES")
    private List<Skill> skills;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;


    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

//[..getters & setters...]

    public void addSkill(Skill skill) {
        this.skills.add(skill);
        skill.addEmployee(this);
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
        this.company.addEmployee(this);
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String companyName;

    private List<Employee> employee;

    public Company() {
    }

    public Company(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

//[..getters & setters...]

    public void setEmployee(List<Employee> employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee.add(employee);
    }
}
```

So, a company can have employees, and an employee can have only one company, but in my database, glasshfish created a table between employee and company.

Employee :

- ID
- FIRSTNAME
- LASTNAME
- COMPANY_ID

Company :

- ID
- COMPANYNAME

Company_Employee :

- Company_ID
- Employee_ID

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to tell JPA that `company.employees` is the inverse side of `employee.company`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private List<Employee> employees;
```

Note that I added a `s` to the name of the field. It's a list of employees, soe there are many of them.